# Run a function after an ad (Google Admob) Android

Tags: android, function, admob

What i want to achieve :

So I have a `ListView` in my app, which has various options... but on clicking any of them, opens a function called `doSomething()`
now what I want to do is, whenever the user clicks on the item in the `ListView`, first a rewarded video ad (Google Admob) should play, and then the function should run. Now the problem is, I will be loading the video ad when the activity is started, and I'll put the function call in the `onRewarded()` and `onRewardedVideoCompleted()` method but what happens when the ad fails to load for some reason, say internet issues or AdMob didn't send an ad, or anything, then I cannot directly put the function call in the `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad()` method as user would not have pressed any ListView item yet. So how do I get around this ? Whenever the user clicks the item, I'll show the ad, and as soon as user closes the ad, or ad is finished the function runs, but how to tackle when the ad failed to load ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

May be I am too late to answer but in the admob reward video , you can configure CallBack URL and implement on what you desired.\

more info here.
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events/rewarded

Answer (score 0):

Inside your doSomething function you can add this condition.

```
    if (yourRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        yourRewardedVideoAd.show();
    } else {
        //proceed to your next routine if ad failed to load
        nextFunction();
    }
```